# CUDA Thread IDs

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm new to CUDA programming and I have the following problem.

If I use the following code to perform matrix multiplication, since CUDA uses Cartesian indexing for thread indexing and C/C++ use row major indexing for matrices, wouldn't it influence the accuracy of the calculation?

```
__global__ void gpuMM(float *A, float *B, float *C, int N)
{
    // Matrix multiplication for NxN matrices C=A*B
    // Each thread computes a single element of C

    int col = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int row = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    float sum = 0.f;
    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        sum += A[row*N+n]*B[n*N+col];

    C[row*N+col] = sum;
}
```

Comment: In which way should row-major ordering and CUDA thread indexing affect the accuracy of calculations?

Comment: Since the ordering is different. For instance when we consider the first row of a matrix it is like [0][0],[0][1],[0][2]....[0][] whereas in CUDA it's (0,0)(1,0)(2,0)...so on

Comment: Then you are worried about _correctness_, not _accuracy_. As @RobertCrovella has answered, you can obtain correct results with row-major ordering. I think there will be also no difference in result accuracy between row-major (e.g., C++) and column-major (Fortran) since the ordering of the operations will be the same (summing `N` numbers in different orders could produce in principle slightly different results).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA doesn't imply any memory storage structure.  You can say CUDA C is row-major for matrix storage, but that is due to C, not CUDA. (CUDA Fortran would be column-major.)  Thread indexing dimensions are arbitrary.  They do not imply a data storage order in memory.

Implications about data storage order in memory of course arise as you write your code.    From a correctness standpoint, it does not matter if we assign row indices based on x thread dimensions or on y thread dimensions.  You can write correct code for this matrix multiply example using either approach (either row based on x, or else row based on y).

However, from a coalescing standpoint, we generally want adjacent executing threads to read or write adjacent cells in memory.  Adjacent threads (for execution) typically are grouped in x first.  Therefore this is preferable (for your kernel code):

```
int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

because it will allow the read of `B[]` and the write of `C[]` to coalesce.

This is easy to prove to yourself.  Try it both ways, and measure the execution time of the kernel.  The results are correct (match the results produced using a host-based matrix multiply) either way, but one formulation runs significantly faster than the other.

This is especially easy to try, since your kernel code implies square matrices.